# using two `\foreach` variables multiplied to select a color mixture

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, foreach

I'm trying to draw a grid with a mix of colors, that changes depending both on the x and y coordinate (MWE):

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \x/\perc in {0/33.3,1.5/66.6} 
    \foreach \y/\percy in {0/0.9,1.5/1.1} 
    \fill[color = green!{\percy*\perc}!red] (\x,\y) rectangle +(1.5cm,1.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This however doesn't work, as it produces:

[image]

Any ideas on how to get that multiplication to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \foreach \x/\perc in {0/33.3,1.5/66.6} 
    {\foreach \y/\percy [evaluate=\percy as \percxy using {int(\perc*\percy)}] in {0/0.9,1.5/1.1} 
    {\fill[color = green!\percxy!red] (\x,\y) rectangle +(1.5cm,1.5cm);}}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot marmot ;-)